# Quote a path in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, quoting

I have a shell script that uses *[base64](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64)* to encode a value and store it in a variable.

```
encoded="$(cat $pathtofile|base64 -w 0)"
```

This worked until I ended up with a `$pathtofile` that had a special character in it. Now I'm trying to figure out how to quote the `$pathtofile` so that cat gets the right file. When I do this

```
encoded="$(cat '$pathtofile'|base64 -w 0)"
```

I end up with an error because it doesn't expand `$pathtofile`, but prints it literally. I have tried several other combinations, but they all result in a misquoted path.

How can I end up with a quoted `$pathtofile`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes can be nested when you use `$(...)`.

```
encoded="$(cat "$pathtofile" | base64 -w 0)"
```

For what it's worth, the outer set of quotes is optional. They're not needed in variable assignments. Remove them if you like.

```
encoded=$(cat "$pathtofile" | base64 -w 0)
```

Also, congratulations, you've won a [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)!

```
encoded=$(base64 -w 0 "$pathtofile")
```

Comment: Thanks for the useless use of cat award ;)